# Using CDI without a Servlet Container

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, java-7

I want to write a simple Java Desktop Application using Java Swing. Usually I use **Spring Framework** to do the dependency injection and build the whole class structure. However, I've seen that **CDI** is becoming more and more popular and want to give it a try.

I would like to do the Dependency Injection of my project using CDI, but I don't know if this is possible without a Servlet container (as it is using Spring). Every single tutorial seems to be related with servlet containers or application servers.

Comment: Searching for "CDI without container" directly revealed some very interesting articles for your topic.

Comment: Not for me @Seelenvirtuose can you give any reference?

Comment: First hit was [Bootstrapping CDI](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2011/01/12/bootstrapping-cdi-in-several-environments/). Second hit was [Control CDI containers](http://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/controlling-cdi-containers-in-se-and-ee/). Maybe these links help you.